# Can I both use SetOnTouchListener(this) and ItemClick in one listview?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Can I both use `SetOnTouchListener(this)` and `ItemClick` in one ListView? Itemclick to get the Item I want and SetOnTouchListener to scroll the ListView up and down. Thank you very much for the big help.

Is this possible?

```
   int yy=0;
   listview.Adapter = adapter;
   listview.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
   listview.ItemClick += listview_ItemClick;

   listview.Scroll += (s, e) => listview.Post(() =>
         {
       // Scrolls to y position 10px
       //listview.ScrollTo(0, 10);
        // or scrolls y by 10 px
       listview.ScrollBy(yy, 10);
      // yy = yy + 10;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use the events. There is an event for Scrolling, too.
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Android.Widget.AbsListView.Scroll/

```
var list = FindViewById<ListView>(...)
list.Scroll += (s,e) => Debug.WriteLine("Scrolled");
```

Example for Question in Comments:

```
list.Post(() =>
{
    // Scrolls to y position 10px
    list.ScrollTo(0, 10);
    // or scrolls y by 10 px
    list.ScrollBy(0, 10);
});
```

Comment: then how can I scroll down and up my listview?

Comment: do you want to scroll it or listen to scrolls?

Comment: I want to scroll the listview. because it has too many items and at the same time i want a select a single item. is it possible?

Comment: These listeners are made for events triggered by the user. If you want to scroll the ListView programatically, you have to use `ScrollBy(int)` https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.AbsListView.ScrollListBy/p/System.Int32/

Comment: ahahahah thanks for that. but I'm a newbie.. do you have a very simple sample?

Comment: is this correct? list.ItemClick += list_ItemClick;

            list.Scroll += (s, e) => Console.Out.WriteLine("Scrolled");
           list.Post(() =>
{
    // Scrolls to y position 10px
    list.ScrollTo(0, 10);
    // or scrolls y by 10 px
    list.ScrollBy(0, 10);
});

Comment: I don't know. Maybe update your question with your current code and maybe screenshot and explain in more detail want you want to achieve.

Comment: *No, you should use the events* Totally wrong, if you can, use the delegates, the events use an inner delegate which then rises the events, slower and error-prone.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Yes, you can't, because that if it's possible always use the delegate and not the events as I said.

Comment: @BlueAries This is possible, but it makes no sense to me. Your code says: _"If the ListView scrolls, scroll it more"_. Could you please describe the behavior you want to achieve? What is wrong and what do you want to change?